# Is there a Char version of the Enum StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Tags: string, dictionary, char

I came across `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` when using dictionary, however my dictionary key value is a char and not a  string. I was wondering, is there a enum version of `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` which you can use in the case of char datatypes? Something like the below:

```
var caseInsensitiveDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

 var caseInsensitiveDictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>(
        CharComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

I am currently concerned about optimal performance, therefore i would not want to go for char.ToUpper() or is there not much noticeable performance difference?